# How to insert 360 video into video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

Does anyone know how to insert a video with a rotation of 360 degrees in the video.js

The only thing I found on this topic is
https://github.com/yanwsh/videojs-panorama
I could write this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
                <title>Название страницы</title>

            <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "skript/video-js.min.css" />
            <script src = "skript/video.min.js"> </script>
            <script src="skript2/three.min.js"></script>
            <link href="skript2/videojs-panorama.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="skript2/videojs-panorama.v5.min.js"></script>
            <script>


var options = {
  plugins: {
    panorama: {
      clickAndDrag: true,
      clickToToggle: true,
      autoMobileOrientation: true
    }
  }
};




     var player = videojs('videojs-panorama-player', options, function () {

});

 player.panorama({
    clickToToggle: true,
    PanoramaThumbnail: true,
    KeyboardControl: true,
    backToHorizonCenter: false,
    backToVerticalCenter: false,
    clickAndDrag: true,
    autoplay: true,
    initFov: 70,
    maxFov: 70,
    minFov: 70,
    mobileVibrationValue:0.032,
    autoMobileOrientation: true,
    VREnable: true,
    NoticeMessage: (isMobile()) ? "drag and drop video text",
    callback: function () {
        if (!isMobile()) player.pause();
    }
});

    </script>


            </head> 
        <body>
        <video
        id="videojs-panorama-player"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
          class="video-js"
          controls
          preload="auto"
          width="640"
          height="264"
          data-setup='{}'>
          <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">

          </video>



          <video
          id="videojs-panorama-player"
      class="video-js"
      controls
      preload="auto"
      width="640"
      height="264"
      data-setup='{}'>
      <source src="https://yanwsh.github.io/videojs-panorama/assets/shark.mp4" type="video/mp4">


      </video>

        </body>


        </html>
```

but it does not work

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 2index.html:1 NoticeMessage: (isMobile()) ? "drag and drop video text",

or

Uncaught TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)
    at videojs (video.js:21690)
    at index.html:47

Tell me please what am I doing wrong

the strange thing is that everything works on the site

https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/JeLqGN

but on localhost gives errors

Comment: accept my answer if it work!

Answer (score 2):

you must first define player then `player.panorama` work, like this :

```
var player = videojs('videojs-panorama-player', options, function () {

});

 player.panorama({
    clickToToggle: true,
    PanoramaThumbnail: true,
    KeyboardControl: true,
    backToHorizonCenter: false,
    backToVerticalCenter: false,
    clickAndDrag: true,
    autoplay: true,
    initFov: 70,
    maxFov: 70,
    minFov: 70,
    mobileVibrationValue:0.032,
    autoMobileOrientation: true,
    VREnable: true,
    NoticeMessage: (isMobile()) ? "drag and drop video text",
    callback: function () {
        if (!isMobile()) player.pause();
    }
});
```

options is an object that you can add some config there

Comment: Sorry for so long
but nothing has changed
I wrote everything at the top